# Google Play allow downloading code?

Tags: javascript, android, web-applications, policy

We have planned to design a Android app to manage/download/execute/delete a zip archive file. Basically, that's

- html5
- css
- javascript
- image

To run that archive file as a independent entity.

I've heard from my colleagues that Apple Store would have DENY this sort of code. Do you think it's doable for Google Play?

Comment: You use Phonegrap? It's ok

Comment: Thanks Marco, I didn't. Some of our requirements is that our customers can customized whatever UI, looking & feeling they want. So my solution is let them to use HTML5

Comment: You should review the terms of service and see if what you want to do is prohibited: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html